# Maven Profile not found

Tags: maven

I have added a simple maven profile to my pom.xml:

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>live</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*LiveTest.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

But it just doesn't seem to get registered? If I run:
`mvn help:active-profiles`

It doesn't list any active profiles. Likewise, `mvn clean install -P live` doesn't invoke the desired tests matching the pattern.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need a profile for a test?

Comment: Because I only want to run these types of tests using a certain profile.

Comment: Please note that this profile will _overwrite_  the surefire plugin configuration, which means that when activating this profile, your original surefire configuration is probably gone.

Comment: It doesn't overwrite anything as it doesn't work ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the space from between "-P" and "live" to activate the profile:

```sh
mvn clean install -Plive
```